# protractor- how to check if elements is present when they have same model name

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Below is my Html code for the textfield. 
In protractor element.all( by.model('phoneNumber.areaCode')) returns me an count of two which is true.
But i need to check each textfield is present or not. so how do i do in order to iterate and check one by one to see if this element is present or not.

Plz help me on this issue.

Note : I just want to go by model locator only and not by any other locator

My Html is below

```
<input disabled="disabled" required="required" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength" digit3="" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{3}$/" name="areaCode" ng-model="phoneNumber.areaCode" maxlength="3" no-validation-on-focus="" ng-change="inputValidate('areaCode')" ng-disabled="disable" ng-required="required" id="areaCode" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a combination of the two existing answers - [`each()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) and `expect()`+[`isDisplayed()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed) is the most common way to check the visibility of every element in the array:

```
var areaCodes = element.all(by.model('phoneNumber.areaCode'));
areaCodes.each(function (areaCode) {
    expect(areaCode.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
});
```

---

You can also [`reduce()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce) the displayedness of multiple elements into a single boolean value and make the expectation once:

```
var areaCodes = element.all(by.model('phoneNumber.areaCode'));
var areAllDisplayed = areaCodes.reduce(function (acc, areaCode) {
    return areaCode.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
        return isDisplayed && acc;
    });
}, true);
expect(areAllDisplayed).toBe(true);
```

---

Also note that you can call `isDisplayed()` on the array of elements which would be a promise which resolves into an array of boolean elements:

```
var areaCodes = element.all(by.model('phoneNumber.areaCode'));
expect(areaCodes.isDisplayed()).toEqual([true, true, true]);
```

---

<sub>All this assumes you were actually intended to check for visibility and not for presence as in your initial question state.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

when you resolve element.all() method it will return you array of web elements as result. Then you can iterate through the array and check whether all elements are present. Try the below code.

```
element.all(by.model('phoneNumber.areaCode')).then(function(arrayOfElement){
  for(i=0;i<arrayOfElement.length;i++){
    expect(arrayOfElement[i].isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot suresh and Sudharsan its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate, you have to apply **each()** method on *element.all()*. Inside the loop you can use protractor.ExpectedConditions to check visibility of each element in loop. You can follow below code:

Code Snippet:

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;
element.all( by.model('phoneNumber.areaCode')).each(function(eachInputField, 
                                                          index){
 expect(EC.visibilityOf(eachInputField).call()).toBe(true,'element at 
                           index'+index+' is not visible');
 });
```